# Getting value from toplevel

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have a problem with getting value from Entry in toplevel. my code:

```
    Wprowadz=Toplevel()
    Wprowadz1=Entry(Wprowadz)
    Wprowadz1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    PrzyciskWprowadz=Button(Wprowadz, text="Wprowadź", width=30, height=2, command= lambda imie=Wprowadz1.get(), nazwisko="nazwisko", dimie=str("dimie"), klasa=str("klasa") : fun_sprowadzdosql(imie, nazwisko, dimie, klasa))
    PrzyciskWprowadz.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

I want to get Wprowadz1 value to pass it to a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the `.get()` method after they click the button. You're calling it when defining the button.

Also, a word of advice: don't use `lambda`, especially not with more than a single function inside. While `lambda` has its uses, code using `lambda` can be hard to read, hard to write, and hard to debug for anything except for the simplest of cases.

```
PrzyciskWprowadz=Button(
    Wprowadz, text="Wprowadź", width=30, height=2, command= callback
)

def callback():
    imie=Wprowadz1.get()
    fun_sprowadzdosql(imie, "nazwisko", "dimie", "klasa")
```

If you prefer to use `lambda`, this will work:

```
PrzyciskWprowadz=Button(
    Wprowadz, text="Wprowadź", width=30, height=2,
    command= lambda wprowadz1=Wprowadz1: fun_sprowadzdosql(wprowadz1.get(), "nazwisko", "dimie", "klasa"))
```